# Explain "Please type another output file name: "

Tags: output

Please, explain why it asks something like this.

```
$ latex full.tex
...

l.5 \begin{document}

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
Please type another output file name:
```

**.full.tex -file**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello 1}

hello my name is \"{a}.

\section{hello my 2}

dad  \"{o}aeoeu\"{a}!

\end{document}
```

**[Comment] not writing -permission issue or privilege -issue**

```
$ ls -lsa .full.tex 
4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 tester tester 160 2011-09-24 02:42 .full.tex
```

Alert: Do not do this on your machine, abusing root.

```
# latex .full.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./.full.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file .full.aux.
latex: Not writing to .full.aux (openout_any = p).
! I can't write on file `.full.aux'.
\document ...ate \openout \@mainaux \jobname .aux 
                                                  \immediate \write \@mainau...
l.5 \begin{document}

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
```

*P.s. I forget to mention -- I am using 11.04 Ubuntu at the moment, not yet tried on other machines. Maybe OS-related prob.*

Comment: The most probable cause is that you don't have writing privileges in the directory the file is in.

Comment: @egreg: wrong, please, look my proof in the updated question.

Comment: See also: [tikz pgf - pgf externalization: problem with point at start of folder name - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392270/pgf-externalization-problem-with-point-at-start-of-folder-name) (setting `openout_any` may relax the restriction)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the dot in the file name. Your document's name is `.full.tex` and this is triggering the error message. Simply rename the file deleting the initial dot.

Or, when prompted to give another output file name, provide a name such as `full.tex`.

Comment: why not ".full.tex"? It would be so easy to compile "$ cat *.tex > .full.tex" and then just "$ latex .\*" -- I currently name my chapters as "1.tex", "2.tex" etc -- well I will do just "$ cat [0-9]\*.tex > full.tex $ latex full.tex", good enough.

Comment: Outputting dot files is a security issue: a malicious TeX source could change important files such as `.profile`; remember that TeX overwrites existing files when it starts writing its output, without asking for permission.